# Vim and MacVim questions

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, homebrew, macvim

Greetings fellow problem solvers.
I'll start by saying my level of expertise regarding coding/anything compsci is somewhere right above ZERO (intro to java last semester & currently teaching myself python, but that's it). Also I have a macbook air running 10.14.6(mojave). Ok, here are my questions.

What I did:
I installed macvim version 8.1.2234 before realizing my machine was shipped with vim 8.0.1365 preinstalled. I installed macvim using the download .dmg & "drag/drop to applications" method.

What I'd like to know:
Firstly, MacVim and Vim appear to be separate programs (when I type **mvim -v** as opposed to **vim -v** in the terminal, each one shows a different version number as described above). So, how can I remove/replace/update/overwrite or whatever, so that I only have *either* macvim or vim? I don't really care which one I have as long as I only have one 
--> Before telling me to just rename an alias so that one maps to the other, please read the info below <--

I REALLY don't want two nearly identical programs on my computer because, a)it seems like a waste a space b)don't want the possibility of accidentally saving something to the wrong place, or calling something from the wrong place, but mostly c)so I can sleep at night.

That being said, do I NEED both? Does macvim rely on vim to work or do they both exist and work independently? Also does renaming an alias mean that the other will be replaced? Because I would assume that just renaming one would be a lot like having two houses, but making both driveways only go to one house.

Additional info:     I have do homebrew but I didn't install macvim using homebrew. I found another post recommending to use (i don't remember exact syntax but something like..) $**brew overwrite vim--with-macvim**. So I thought great, I'll uninstall macvim since I haven't used it at all yet, and then I'll re-download using the homebrew overwrite method. But then I read that it's a little more complicated than moving the "Vim" folder to the trash, and after two unsuccessful attempts in the terminal that looked like this:
**$brew uninstall mvim** (throws no keg error)
**$brew uninstall macvim** (same error)
I decided to reach out for help before I break anything.

Thanks in advance for any info/advice, it is much appreciated!

Comment: PS if you didnt install mvim with brew, you cant uninstall it that way.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t have time for a longer explanation at the moment, but:

**Breathe Easy**

MacVim is nearly completely independent from (terminal) vim. They do share your vimrc, but MacVim also reads gvimrc, and uses its own runtime directories.

You’re not wasting much space, and it would be a Bad Idea™️ to mess with the system installation of some programs.